# Is there a way I can set the settings of a json serializer when it is constructed?

Tags: c#

In my app every time the JsonSerializer is used this always appears first.

JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = Helpers.JsonSerializer.EscapeHtmlSerializer();

for example:

```
    public void UpdateD(D1 d)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = Helpers.JsonSerializer.EscapeHtmlSerializer();
        ...
        var serializeJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dconf, jsonSerializerSettings); ;
        ...
    }
```

where:

```
public static partial class JsonSerializer
{
    public static JsonSerializerSettings EscapeHtmlSerializer()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
        };
        return jsonSerializerSettings;
    }
}
```

Is there a way this could be simplified? For example a way that I could make a new JsonConvert that already had the settings?

Comment: ...Wrap these two up in a single method?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - can you give an example of what you mean in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "make a new `JsonConvert`", because `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is a static method, and static members are not polymorphic.

What you can do, however, quite easily - is simply to write a method to bind these two steps together:

```
// Inside the Helpers namespace, in JsonConverter class...
public static string SerializeEscapeHtml(object content)
    => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, JsonSerializer.EscapeHtmlSerializer());
```

and then, in your `update` method - simply do this:

```
var serializeJson = Helpers.JsonConverter.SerializeEscapeHtml(dconf);
```

If you're using the `EscapeHtmlSerializer()` often, you might consider creating a static property and initialize it once instead of generating new `JsonSerializerSettings` every single time:

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings EscapeHtmlSerializer {get;} = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
    };
```

and then change the method to

```
public static string SerializeEscapeHtml(object content)
    => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, JsonSerializer.EscapeHtmlSerializer);
```

This doesn't look like much of a change, but it should slightly improve memory allocation since now you only use a single instance of the `JsonSerializerSettings` throughout the lifetime of the program instead of generating an instance of it every time you serialize something to json.

**Update:**

The `JsonConverter` class

```
namspace Helpers
{
    public static class JsonConverter 
    {
        public static string SerializeEscapeHtml(object content)
            => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, JsonSerializer.EscapeHtmlSerializer);
    }
    // Whatever more code you need here
}
```

The `JsonSerializer` class

```
namspace Helpers
{
    public static class JsonSerializer 
    {
        public static JsonSerializerSettings EscapeHtmlSerializer {get;} = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
        };
    }
    // Whatever more code you need here
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  That is a really nice solution.  Just to make it a bit more clear, can you include the full code that would go inside the Helpers namespace for the classes for all the snippets.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad to help :-)